# How to find out where HTML navigation was triggered

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, google-chrome-devtools

I have to inspect a large scaled HTML front end project where a page load occurs after jQuery Javascript AJAX request. But I cannot find out why and where a HTML navigation was executed. Does there a exists a way to watch or stop at such an event in chrome dev tools? I just took a look if there is a form or submit button on the page. But there is nothing not even a form. I am pretty sure HTML navigation was triggered by Javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, there is options available for **Event Listener Breakpoints**. It will be in source panel and you can have a variety of event breakpoints.

For more, detailed reference - [Chrome Breakpoints Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)